# CodeIgniter - Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Password.(pword_check)

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, hmvc

I am a new to codeIgniter and I just got stuck in the very beginning. I am using HMVC extention and while validating I am getting the following error:

**Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Password.(pword_check)**

any help would be greatly appreciated

Code:

```
public function submit()
{


    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|max_length[30]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pword', 'Password', 'required|max_length[30]|callback_pword_check|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->login();
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Success'; die();
    }
}

public function pword_check($str)
{

    if ($str == 'test')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('pword_check', 'The %s field can not be the word "test"');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of CI you use???

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter Version 3.0.1

Answer (score 18):

> xss_clean is no longer part of form validation in Codeingitore 3

Just remove `xss_clean` from your validation roul

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pword', 'Password', 'required|max_length[30]|callback_pword_check');
```

If you really, really need to apply that rule, you should now also load the Security Helper, which contains `xss_clean()` as a regular function and therefore can be also used as a validation rule.

go to `application/config/autoload.php :`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('security');
```

Or, before your form validation

```
$this->load->helper('security');
```

Comment: Thanks for you valuable time. I have already tried removing xss_clean thing also I have auto loaded the security helper but error message is still getting displayed for password field.

Comment: It's a very simple code I don't know what is causing this error.

Comment: change your message to `$this->form_validation->set_message('pword_check', "The %s field can not be the word test");` and check

Comment: I changed the message to yours but it did't help, again same error (Unable to access an error message ) is getting displayed.

Comment: This peice of code looks okk. My be problem is with some other part

Comment: hmmm. but its strange.

Answer (score 14):

Hello Guys I found the solution for working with call_backs in hmvc codeIgniter.
I would like to post the solution for others.

**Solution:**

**1. Create MY_Form_validation.php file in libraries folder and paste following code in it.**

```
 if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
    {

    function run($module = '', $group = '')
    {
       (is_object($module)) AND $this->CI = &$module;
        return parent::run($group);
    }
}
```

2. **And change `if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)`  to   `if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE)`** thats all folks..

Comment: added to libraries in CI 3.0.x, @kev_m

Comment: Can we have an explanation as to why this works? Thanks a million by the way, saved my life!

Comment: million thanx, Just a suggestion , you dont need to create the library, instead just pass $this in run function and you are all set 
`$this->form_validation->run($this)`

Answer (score 3):

```
public function pword_check($str)
{

    if ($str == 'test')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message(  __FUNCTION__ , 'The %s field can not be the word "test"');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

// Its working well

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/3908

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written

Answer (score 1):

For future searches. There are two **3** things you need to check when this error shows.

1. Check the name of the callback function if it is the same with the

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('pword', 'Password', 'required|max_length[30]|callback_**pword_check**

   ```
   public function pword_check($str){                                              
     if ($str == 'test'){
       $this->form_validation->set_message('pword_check', 'The %s field can not be the word "test"');
       return FALSE;
     }
     else{
       return TRUE;
     }                                                                              
   }
   ```

   > *public function **pword_check**($str){
   >
   > *set_message('**pword_check**', 'The %s field...
2. In codeigniter 2.X you can do this

   > $this->form_validation->run($this) == TRUE

   In 3.x it should be like this

   > $this->form_validation->run() == TRUE

   and you need to add this two line of codes on __construct()

   ```
   function __construct(){                                     
     parent::__construct();                                                      
     $this->load->library('form_validation');
     $this->form_validation->CI =& $this;                                           
   }
   ```
3. Add this file on your application/libraries/**MY_Form_validation.php**

   ```
   <?php                                                                
   class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation{                                     
       public $CI;                                                                                               
   }
   ```

Cheers! See https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/src/f77a3fc9a6fd?at=codeigniter-3.x

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pp4Y_bIhASY&list=PLBEpR3pmwCayNcTCUWlUToK4qIQfFQCCm&index=8

For reference.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is
you didn't loaded the security helper the following is the way enable security helper
with autoload.php in config folder or you can directly load the helper as mentioned last line of this post

And if, despite everything, you really need it, go to application/config/autoload.php :

$autoload['helper'] = array('security');
Or, before your form validation
$this->load->helper('security');

Answer (score 0):

before going to the helper security check on the file `application/config/autoload.php` 
add form_validation in librariies

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation');
```

and don't forget to add security

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('security');
```

try it