# 'Security' helper not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter v 3.1.4. In one of the form, i have a text box to save urls (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, http://google.com etc.) into the MySql database.

Before save, i am sanitizing the urls like shown below:

Inside Constructor:

```
$this->load->helper('security');
```

Inside Add function:

```
$hlt_url    = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('txtHLnk'));
$hlt_hlines = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('txtAreaHLine'));
```

When i enter simple/plain string in the textboxes, then the data gets saved in the DB, however when i enter url in the textboxes, the data is not saved in DB, neither does it show any error message.

Please explain with code whats i am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665715/codeigniter-unable-to-access-an-error-message-corresponding-to-your-field-name/32665869#32665869

Answer (score 0):

`$hlt_url    = $this->input->post('txtHLnk', true);
$hlt_hlines = $this->input->post('txtAreaHLine', true);`

I thin kthis is the new implementation of sanitizing inputs in latest version.

Comment: Note: you can also remove helper on top

Comment: Still no luck @Randy.When i hit the submit button, the page does not reload and the inputs from the textbox just erases/vanishes